# QNetworkAccessManager fails

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am following this doc   http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt  trying to implement an http connection and my code compiles without error, but when the program launches, it crashes.

//coreeng.cpp

```
#include "coreeng.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>

coreEng::coreEng(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void coreEng::connect(){
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void coreEng::url(){
    QUrl url("http://www.forum.nokia.wiki");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void coreEng::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

    delete reply;

}
```

//coreeng.h

```
#ifndef COREENG_H
#define COREENG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class coreEng : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
        public:
            explicit coreEng(QObject *parent = 0);
        private slots:

        public slots:
            void connect();
            void url();
            void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);


        private:
            QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

};

#endif // COREENG_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "coreeng.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    coreEng mConnect;
    mConnect.connect();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pay more attention to your c++ code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* nam;
```

`nam` is used but is never created. You should create it in `coreEng` constructor:

```
coreEng::coreEng(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), nam( new QNetworkAccessManager(this) )
{
}
```

Another issue is:

```
delete reply;
```

Qt [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) say:

> Do not delete the reply object in the slot connected to this signal. Use deleteLater().

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. do you mean like this?    explicit coreEng(QObject *parent = 0)
            {
                QNetworkAccessManager* nam;
            }

Comment: No. That would create a local variable on the stack with a lifetime limited to that of the constructor. Something like `nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();` should do it. With all due respect, based on your series of questions, you may want to consider a C++ course.

Comment: I get bad errors when I make my constructor look like that   http://i.imgur.com/Fl2VAYK.png

Comment: @brad, please compare your constructor and my constructor. Find the difference.

Comment: copy/paste = christmas tree lights. extra qualifier error is the first